# "Odd" Behavior When Touching Views

Tags: ios

I am playing with views. My application is simple:

1. I have a custom view controller and its associated view, call it mainView. My custom view controller overrides the touchesBegan method. My touchesBegan method adds a border to the view that was touched and removes the border from the previously touched view (if any). Thus I have a visual indication of which view was last touched.

   ```
   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   print("There are \(touches.count) touch(es)")
   if let selectedView = self.selectedView {
       selectedView.borderWidth = 0
   }
   self.selectedView = touches.first?.view
   if let selectedView = self.selectedView {
       selectedView.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor()
       selectedView.borderWidth = 2
   }
   ```

   }
2. To the main view I have added a sub view, call it subView.
3. To subView I have added 2 sub views, call them subSubView1 and subSubView2.

[image]

As I touch the views their borders appear and disappear as I would expect. But, if I reposition subSubView1 (or subSubView2) such that it is partially inside of and partially outside of subView, then the behavior becomes "odd". If I touch the portion of subSubView1 that overlaps subView then subSubView1 receives the border. If I touch the portion of subSubView1 that overlaps mainView then it is mainView that receives the border. Would someone please help me to understand this behavior?

Xcode 7.3, debugging with an iPhone 6 Simulator.

Comment: Try this: `mainView.bringSubviewToFront(touchedView)`.  Put this line when you touch a `subView`.

Comment: The view is not selectable if it's positioned outside of it's parent.  I would assume that the touch event is bubbling up from the bottom (mainView).  Then it goes to mainView's children.  If the touch is not in that child it stops.  So the part of the sub-sub view that is not in it's parent will not receive touch events that are not in it's parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view is not selectable if it's positioned outside of it's parent. I would assume that the touch event is bubbling up from the bottom (mainView). Then it goes to mainView's children. If the touch is not in that child it stops. So the part of the sub-sub view that is not in it's parent will not receive touch events that are not in it's parent.

See [this question](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa2013/qa1812.html) for more information.

Copied text in case that link is behind a login wall.

> Q: My view is displayed correctly on the screen, but does not receive any touch events. Why is that?
>
> A: The most common cause of this problem is because your view is located outside the bounds of its parent view. When your application receives a touch event, a hit-testing process is initiated to determine which view should receive the event. The process starts with the root of the view hierarchy, typically the application's window, and searches through the subviews in front to back order until it finds the frontmost view under the touch. That view becomes the hit-test view and receives the touch event. Each view involved in this process first tests if the event location is within its bounds. Only after the test is successful, does the view pass the event to the subviews for further hit-testing. So if your view is under the touch but located outside its parent view's bounds, the parent view will fail to test the event location and won't pass the touch event to your view.